# AnyLogic: How i know i have multiple networks and solve that problem?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

The agent is not following the outlined path for moving to its destination
because destination is in different network.
How i know i have multiple networks and how to avoided that. So agents move on the path.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to see if you have multiple networks, you can check on the projects panel
[image: network]
Here you will see all the networks you have, and what nodes are contained inside each network.

AnyLogic doesn't know automatically how to connect these 2 networks if you want to do it, so you need to have attention to details when you build your networks.

if your agent move between nodes that are not in the same network, you will get unexpected results

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of networks by calling `getNetworks()`.

You can loop through them using

```
for (INetwork currentNetwork :getNetworks()) {
    // do something with currentNetwork
}
```

Check my current video series on making networks a lot more powerful, including the problem of having several networks: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2022/8/6/taking-control-of-your-network-agent-based-pathfinding

Comment: I read your Blog and also watch the introduction video of agent-based AnyLogic Networks. Let me know where I can find the complete 6-part video series about that.
I am very excited to learn and implement agent-based AnyLogic Networks.

Comment: being published over the coming days and weeks

Answer (score 0):

When **paths** and the destination **node" do not connect with each other, then the agent does not follow the path and uses the shortest path to reach its destination.

A **Network** is the collection of paths and nodes that we create on canvas.
If we create multiple collections of paths and nodes and do not connect one collection with the other, then they act as separate networks.